# Shopify API redirecting to login page on authorization request?

Tags: ruby, shopify

I am new to Shopify App development using a demo app and a demo shop with the [ShopifyAPI Ruby API](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api)

In the third step mentioned on github, I have to make a `GET` request with parameters as: 
`client_id` – the API key for the app and `scope`.

And in the 4th step it says - Once authorized, the shop redirects the owner to the return URL of your application with a parameter named 'code'.

When I make this `GET` request, I am redirected to my shop for login not to the return URL of application. But whenever I am logged in in my admin console, I am able to get the `code` which can be further used. Since the app can be used by many shops, I need to get the `code` to get authorization. I am lost here a bit. Please suggest how to get the code from the third step.

Comment: Hi Nihal, I am also facing this problem. though this is several years old post did you solve this ?